# How does the water passing Dike Kokaral compare to the discharge of the Syr Darya river before its water flow was improved?

Tags: rivers, lakes, dams

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aral_Sea#North_Aral_Sea_restoration_work), the North Aral Sea is being partially restored, by restoring some of the Syr Darya river's flow (which was diverted by the Soviet Union for irrigation), and by building [Dike Kokaral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dike_Kokaral) to keep water in the North Aral Sea instead of flowing to the south.

Looking through images on Google, you can see that Dike Kokaral still at least occasionally lets water through, which made me wonder as to whether the South Aral Sea was receiving as much water as before the dam, thanks to the improved flow of Syr Darya.

- **What is the yearly discharge of the dam?**
- **What was the yearly discharge of the Sy Darya river before irrigation works were repaired and improved?**

[image: Dike Kokaral letting water through]